# some markdown files into one pdf document

Tags: pdf, markdown, gitbook

I have approximately 20 files in markdown type and I need to convert those into one pdf document. I try using online converter, but the images are not showing, it just like `![alt text](image.png)`

Using Calibre app also not showing images.

Btw, I am using Gitbook to generate my markdown and html view, I read the documentation about how to convert into pdf using `gitbook pdf`in command line, but it returns `TypeError`

Does anyone know how to solve this? I am using Windows 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can use the **Pandoc** tool (it runs on Windows/MacOS/Linux).

It is an command line tool which can easily convert your Markdown file into PDF (or other kind of format).

> [Take a look to Pandoc website](http://pandoc.org/installing.html)

Maybe you will have to install a LaTeX environnement like [Miktex](https://miktex.org/) in order to convet into PDF.

An example from Pandoc documentation :

> From markdown to PDF:
>
> `pandoc myInput.md --latex-engine=xelatex -o myOutput.pdf`

Furthermore, there is several interesting options if you want to generate a table of contents in your output for instance.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I have a problem with `xelatex not found`. I have installed the `Miktex` you suggest me. I dont know whats wrong..

Comment: Normally `Xelatex` is included in your `Miktex` installation directory (`... miktex/bin/x64/xelatex.exe` on WIndows). Maybe you can try specifying the full path of xelatex in the `--latex-engine` option.
Plus, you can alternatively use the `wkhtmltopdf` engine to export PDF (the output looks like document save as PDF in your browser...). For that use `pandoc myInput.md -t html5 -o myOutput.pdf`